when I payment using payu then it is getting crash in flutter iOS
No payment option found error in flutter iOS device for payment gateway
 showPaymentOption() {     onlineDepositeProvider         .getinitiatGatWayTrasaction(             "2", "4", amountController.text, "UPI", context)         .then((value) {           print("getinitiatGatWayTrasaction response ===== ${value.error}");       if (value.error == "0") {         checksum = value.checkSum;         salt = value.salt;         value.gateWayData.forEach((element) {           userId = element.userid.toString();           merchantKey = element.merchantKey;           callbackurl = element.callbackurl;           email = element.email;           mobile = element.mobile;           fullname = element.fullname;           txnid = element.txnid;         });         checkoutPro!.openCheckoutScreen(           payUPaymentParams: {           PayUPaymentParamKey.key: merchantKey,           PayUPaymentParamKey.amount: amountController.text,           PayUPaymentParamKey.productInfo: userId,           PayUPaymentParamKey.firstName: fullname,           PayUPaymentParamKey.email: email,           PayUPaymentParamKey.phone: mobile,           PayUPaymentParamKey.environment: "0",           // String - "0" for Production and "1" for Test           PayUPaymentParamKey.transactionId: txnid,           // transactionId Cannot be null or empty and should be unique for each transaction. Maximum allowed length is 25 characters. It cannot contain special characters like: -_/           PayUPaymentParamKey.userCredential: ":1000",           //  Format: <merchantKey>:<userId> ... UserId is any id/email/phone number to uniquely identify the user.           PayUPaymentParamKey.android_surl: callbackurl,           PayUPaymentParamKey.android_furl: callbackurl,           PayUPaymentParamKey.ios_surl: callbackurl,           PayUPaymentParamKey.ios_furl: callbackurl,         }, payUCheckoutProConfig: {           PayUCheckoutProConfigKeys.merchantName: fullname,         }).then((value){           print("value ============== $value");         });         isEnable = true;         setState(() {});       }     });   } No payment option error show in flutter iOS but it work perfectly for android but when I am test it in iOS then it is not working , I have tried it many times but not work it properly. 


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"Please check your order ID; it contains special characters. Remove them, and it will work smoothly."
"And if it still doesn't work, override the onError function and print the response. Find the error in the error message."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
